# Search with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, search, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a domain object `Item`:
Item fields: `a`, `b`, `c`
It has a lot more fields in reality.

I know I can create methods like:

- `findByAAndB(...)`
- Use `@Query(SELECT ... WHERE ...)` on my custom find method

But I still wonder if there is a better solution: What is the easiest to query the `items` table given that I may have a bunch of fields to query for at the same time?

If I have a method as shown below, is there a way that automatically maps the fields that are say `!= null` into a `SELECT`?

- `findBy(Item prototype)`

Comment: Im not sure i understand your question but this link will surely help https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation IsNotNull,NotNull
findByAge(Is)NotNull

Comment: Let's say my Item has 100 fields. The keywords in Table 4 of the documentation would allow me to write a method where I have to iterate all the fields and stuff them into a method name `findByAAndBAndCAndDAndE...AndXAndYAndZ(...)`. That does not appear like a very nice way to me when you deal with a lot of fields. I was wondering if there is a way to autowire all the fields that I have in my `Item` (they are already defined in the class, maybe there is a way that I don't have to repeat myself) to the Query.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example maybe this then i think this is exactly what you need

Comment: Yes, that looks exactly like what I am looking for. Thank you! If you create an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class Item{
      String a,b,c;
    }


    Item item=new Item();
    item.setA("a");
    Example<Item> itemExample=ExampleOf(item);
    List<Item> res=itemRepository.findAll(example);
```

Source: [Query By Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom query with entity manager and create dynamic query. for this you have to define all variable with default `-1`,  which you have  to use in query, then get the all variable  ache check then value is change or not if change the add variable into query and execute it.

ex.

```
StringBuilder tempQuery = new StringBuilder("select " + select + " FROM 
Area area ");

    // cityId
    if (cityId != -1) {
        tempQuery.append(" and ");
        tempQuery.append(" area.FCity.cityId = :cityId ");
    }
    // rId
    if (rId != -1) {
        tempQuery.append(" and ");
        tempQuery.append(" area.FRestaurantCenter.FRestaurant = :rId ");
    }

    return tempQuery.toString();
```

Comment: See comment above, I am wondering if there is way for me to get around writing boilerplate code like this. After all that is one reason why I am using Spring.